# Change image and text color when hovering

Tags: html, css

I have code like this http://jsfiddle.net/enr54x1z/
And when hovering, I want

- to change table cell background color to #317EAC
- to change text to white color
- change cat image to another image

Please HELLPPPP

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: I can't deal with it. I don't know how to change <p> color in td:hover

Comment: `td:hover {
  color: #317EAC;
}` this will change the color of the table cell on hover

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I know that. But how can I change text color and image

Comment: Please help. I really need this

Comment: @Narek :  [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897737/mouseover-event-to-change-td-background-and-text) will help you change the color of the text in td

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEekg/2/)  for it!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Thank you, I will test it later. Really appreciate your work. But I need to also change image to another image when hovering

Comment: @Narek : Please see my answer and tell me if it is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/enr54x1z/3/

In order to change the picture you have to remove the `img` tag and replace it with a `div` that has a `background-image`

the `td:hover` in the CSS is activated once you hover over the `<td>` element. Thus the following background color is applied on hover.

```
td:hover{
    background-color:#317EAC;
}
```

You can extend this to apply other CSS styles when this element is being hovered over. With the following, once the `<td>` is hovered, we go to a child element and apply the color change CSS.

```
td:hover p{
  color:white;
}
```

The same method is used to change the picture on hover:

```
td:hover .img-block {
  background-image:url("http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg");
}
```

Comment: can you also show me the way I can change text color and I leave you "best answer" mark

Comment: Sure, give me a second

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .imgBox { 
    width: 191px; 
    height: 191px; 
    background: url(image-url) no-repeat; } 

    .imgBox:hover 
    { width: 191px; height: 191px; background: 

    url(other-image-url) no-repeat; } 
    </style>

//your markup can be a div inside your td
    <div class="imgBox"> 
    </div>
```

On image-hover u need to simply give another url of a image!

[Here](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html) is an example of what you want!

Comment: Thank you so much for everything but Alexei presented more complete description. Sorry